# SUM() works fine in select statement but returns NULL in Insert statement

Tags: sql, insert, null, sum

I'm creating a script that sums up profits and losses (PL) by certain IDs Matrix ID. I use the following SQL statement against a view "vw_package":

```
select trade_matrix_id, sum(pl) from vw_package 
where date (gen_timestamp) between '2012-05-01' and '2012-05-30' 
and trade_matrix_id between 30 and 60
group by trade_matrix_id;
```

It produces correctly this result:

```
trade_matrix_id,sum(pl)
41,            -147.33
42,             -27.45
43,            -329.03
44,            -329.03
45,            -329.03
...
```

Now I want to fill a table with exactly those results. I create a table in my script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PLByMatrixID 
    (trade_matrix_id    int,
    Sum_PL              float(19,2));
```

I use an INSERT command to populate the table with exactly the same SELECT statement from above:

```
insert into PLByMatrixID (trade_matrix_id, Sum_PL)
   select trade_matrix_id, sum(pl) from vw_package 
   where date (gen_timestamp) between '2012-05-01' and '2012-05-30' 
   and trade_matrix_id between 30 and 60
   group by trade_matrix_id;
```

I call the script and query the result tablePLByMatrixID and all the values in PL are NULL:

```
41,            NULL
42,            NULL
43,            NULL
...
```

I appreciate if anyone could tell me what I'm missing here.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the results correctly? Perhaps there is an error there. The insert statement looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   select trade_matrix_id, sum(pl)
   into PLByMatrixID 
   from vw_package 
   where date (gen_timestamp) between '2012-05-01' and '2012-05-30' 
   and trade_matrix_id between 30 and 60
   group by trade_matrix_id;
```

Comment: A Select into certainly works if there's no additional data down the road, but it would be nice to get to the bottom of why the insert is failing.

Comment: ypercube: I'm not sure what you mean with your question if I'm reading the result correct. I run a select * from PLByMatrixID and the column PL contains only NULL. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: BaN3: When I try that MySQL comes back with "Undeclared Variable: PLByMatrixID". I also tried create table PlByMatrixID as select .... in the hopes that it would create the PL column in the correct format (float (19,2) but that didn't help either. I have the suspicion that it either a conversion issue or that MySQL doesn't like the SUM() and group by.